# How to set all featured products to none featured and then select random products and set them as featured

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to create a script outside WordPress that will set automatically all featured products to none featured and then select 8 random products and set them as featured.

I am working on that part where I fetch featured products IDs and then set them as none featured, but the desired result is not forthcoming, any advice?

```php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php';
global $wpdb;

global $product;
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'      => $products,
    'orderby'             => $orderby,
    'order'               => $order == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    'post__in'            => wc_get_featured_product_ids(),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

    $product = wc_get_product( $query->post->ID );
    $product->set_featured(false);
    $product->save();

endwhile; wp_reset_query();endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the featured products you can use:

- [wc_get_products or WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

And loop through the results to make featured products false:

```php
// Args
$args = array(
    'status'    => 'publish', // Post status
    'include'   => wc_get_featured_product_ids(), // Only includes products with IDs in the array - Returns an array containing the IDs of the featured products
);

// Get products with certain arguments
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $products ) ) {
    // Loop through
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        // None featured
        $product->set_featured( false );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Then you apply something similar:

```php
// Args
$args = array(
    'status'    => 'publish', // Post status
    'limit'     => 8, // Maximum number of results to retrieve or -1 for unlimited
    'orderby'   => 'rand', // Get some random products
    'exclude'   => wc_get_featured_product_ids(), // Excludes products with IDs in the array. - Returns an array containing the IDs of the featured products
);

// Get products with certain arguments
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $products ) ) {
    // Loop through
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        // Featured
        $product->set_featured( true );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

---

**OR** the 2 functions above processed into 1 function:

```php
// Args
$args = array(
    'status'    => 'publish', // Post status
    'limit'     => -1, // Maximum number of results to retrieve or -1 for unlimited
    'orderby'   => 'rand', // Get some random products
);

// Get products with certain arguments
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $products ) ) {
    // Counter
    $counter = 0;

    // Loop through
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        // When featured
        if ( $product->get_featured() ) {
            // None featured
            $product->set_featured( false );
            $product->save();
        }

        // Random products up untill 8 and none featured
        if ( $counter < 8 && ! $product->get_featured() ) {
            // Make featured true
            $product->set_featured( true );
            $product->save();

            // Counter = counter + 1
            $counter ++;
        }
    }
}
```